Integrating OpenAI API into a Pyscript page - Requests keep timing out
I have a Pyscript page that searches a news archive and returns a list of news summaries. I want to then feed this list of summaries into gpt-4o and get back a brief summary of the material. The problem I'm encountering is that my request keeps timing out before anything can happen. Using the exact same request in a Jupyter notebook produced the desired results, so I'm thinking the problem might have something to do with Pyscript. After reading OpenAI forums, i tried setting timeout, but this had no effect. I suspect that OpenAI's 600ms default timeout is being applied but I don't know how to change this when importing the package. Notably, importing openai to my page required also importing ssl, and I think pyscript imports openssl, so maybe there's a conflict? If you can see what I'm doing wrong or if there's a better way to do my OpenAI request in Pyscript, I'd love to hear about it. Here's the function doing the request:
@when('click', '#summary-btn')
async def send(event=None):
    Element('summarybrief').write("Send function successfully called.")
    
    userElement = js.document.getElementById('brief')
    OPENAI_API_KEY = userElement.value.strip()
    client = OpenAI(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, timeout=60.0,  max_retries=3)

    # Convert similar_items to string format
    global similar_items
    similar_items_str = ""
    for index, row in similar_items.iterrows():
        similar_items_str += f"Title: {row['Title']} Summary: {row['Summary']} Note: {row['Note']}"

    payload = f"Using br html tags instead of /n for line breaks, please generate a 500 word narrative summary of the following information: '''{similar_items_str}'''"
    
    #confirm payload is correctly formed
    #Element('summarybrief').element.innerHTML = payload

    chat_completion = client.chat.completions.create(
    messages=[
        {
            "role": "user",
            "content": payload        }
    ],
    model="gpt-4o",
    )
    
    # Log the request data for debugging
    console.log(f"Data: {messages}")

    # Display the response in the summarybrief div
    Element('summarybrief').element.innerHTML = chat_completion

    # Debugging log
    console.log(reply)

I tried making an OpenAI API request from a Pyscript page. I was expecting the request to work as it did in a Jupyter notebook. Instead, the request keeps failing due to timeout.

Do you see any errors in the browser's development console? And which browser are you using?

Tried firefox and chrome. The timeout error in the console reads: File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/_base_client.py", line 971, in _request     raise APITimeoutError(request=request) from err openai.APITimeoutError: Request timed out. Notably, the exact same call from Jupyter works perfectly.
